# neo4j cypher find nodes with same first character of a string property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a bunch of `:Person` nodes which have a string property called name. They are connected with `:CHILD_OF` edges. Now I want to find all `:Person` nodes who are connected to another `:Person` node and they should have the first character fo the name-property in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple WHERE clause comparing the first position of each name property with the [substring()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/string/#functions-substring) function:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:CHILD_OF]->(p2:Person)
WHERE substring(p1.name, 0, 1) = substring(p2.name, 0, 1)
RETURN p1, p2
```